# React native redux-saga request only work with debugger

Tags: react-native, debugging, axios, redux-saga, react-native-debugger

I'm using redux saga as middleware and call my request in this layer. When enable react-native debugger request works prefect, but without the debugger it seems request is not async anymore.

```
export function* userLoginSaga(action) {
    yield put(actions.userLoginStart());
    const response = yield GET(`${action.server}`, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }, {
        username: action.username,
        password: action.password
    });
    if (response === 503) {
        yield put(actions.serverErrorSuccess(response))
    } else if (response.status === 200) {
        yield put(actions.userLoginSuccess(response.data));
    }
}
```

without react debugger, i get "undefined is not an object (response.status) ".
It's not waiting for response to get the result.
Please note that everything is working fine with debugger.

Comment: Is `GET` a native react-native function or is your own wrapper? If so can you provide the definition of it?

Comment: It's my own wrapper. Inside of GET is axios.get with promise handler.

Comment: export const GET = async (url,headers,auth) =>{

    const call = await axios.get(url,{headers:headers,data:{},auth:auth})
        .then(response => {
            return response
        })
        .catch(error=>{

            if(error.message.includes("Network Error")){
                return 503
            }
            else if(error.response && error.response.status >= 500){
                return 503
            }
            else{
                return error.response
            }
           
        })
    return call
}

Comment: I'd try debugging the GET method, e.g. add some logging into the `then` callback to check if you are receiving right data at the righ time. Another log after the `yield GET...`  to compare with the first one and to make sure the code execution is really getting there before it should.

Comment: Thanks Martin, when you said what's inside the GET, it made me to check it out and i found the issue. The GET is async await and looks like you can't yield an async await function. i removed the async/await and now it's working fine.